# Limits of a function, epsilon delta approach

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 2} x^2=4.$$

The answer is $4$, why not $3.98$ or a number other than $4$ - as in a number close to $4$. But why $4$.

I have only basic idea about limits, as in the denominator is not equal to zero, so direct substitution will work here. I tried understanding the epsilon delta approach, but I cannot get the clear picture.

Comment: Why not $3.98$? Because why not $3.99$? And, why not $3.9999998$? Because we can do better. The point of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ is to show that when $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $c$, $f(x)$ also gets arbitrarily close to $L$. Is this the intuitive explanation you are looking for? If not, have you actually tried applying the definition?

Comment: can someone using epsilon delta definition tell me how to discard the answer 3.9999999999999999999999999999999   if i give you epsilon, won't i be able to find delta which will keep the function close to 3.999999999999999999999999...

Comment: i really don't get the idea ... of why exactly 4. as in when it is 4... i give you any epsilon, we say that we are able to find some delta... some delta which will ensure that the function stays close to 4... so what is wrong with 3.999999999999999999999999... 999999.... 9999... 999 as many 9s i want

Comment: 3.9999... (infinite string of 9s) is exactly equal to 4. This is since 0.9999....= 1, and there are rigorous proofs of this out there if you search for it.

Comment: yes i know... but i am saying a finite number of 9's. say 100 of them, but a finite number of 9's.

Comment: If it's a finite number of 9s, then I can immediately find another delta value that will make an even closer estimate (i.e. epsilon falls even more). And so on ad infinitum.

Comment: so for 4 one won't be able to find another delta? please can you elaborate. I am not able to clear the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In general if f(x) is is defined for x = a and is continuous around x = a, then $\lim_{x \to a} = f(a)$.

Comment: $f$ should be continuous at $a$.

Comment: But now you have to prove that $x^2$ is continuous...

Comment: to prove continuity, we have to first prove that the limit exists and now the whole question is why the limit is 4. can someone using the basics, prove me for 3.9999 for a given epsilon i will not be able to find delta but for 4, it is always possible to find delta.

Answer (score 0):

Abishek,

it says "there is delta, so that for *every* x in the delta-neighborhood of 2, the function $f(x)$ will be close to the limit". Since 2 belongs to the neighborhood, your value should be close to 4. But 3.9999 does not work, take $\epsilon = 0.00005$